# android menu does nothing

Tags: java, android, android-intent

We are targeting android 2.2+

I am trying to use androids built in system regarding the hardware menu button still found on many phones. However I have had no luck and no error message:

**/res/menu/optionsmenu.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:id="@+id/menuHelp"
          android:title="Help"
          />
    <item android:id="@+id/menuShowInstallationCode"
          android:title="Show Installation Code"
          />
</menu>
```

**in the activity class**

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu){
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.optionsmenu, menu);
    return(super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu));
}


public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item){
    switch (item.getItemId()){
        case R.id.menuHelp :
            return true;

        case R.id.menuShowInstallationCode :
            return true;

        default:
            return super.onContextItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

The result so far is, that I press the menu button and nothing happens. Really nothing, no error message, no menu, nothing.

I would like a menu to appear. Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: What version of Android are you testing this on? What is the content of the `<uses-sdk>` element in your manifest?

Comment: `<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8"/>` testing on android 2.3 emulator and ICS physical tablet.

Comment: What you have looks OK, other than missing icons in your menu XML (which, IIRC, should be OK). You might try running this old sample project from one of my books to see how it works: https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-android/tree/master/Menus/Inflation Or, consider switching to using action bars, with ActionBarSherlock for your backwards compatibility needs.

Comment: You override `onOptionsItemSelected()`, but then you call `super.onContextItemSelected()` in your `default` section.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should return true in `onCreateOptionsMenu()` and return `super.onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)` in `onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)` after switch statement. Please change to:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu){
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.optionsmenu, menu);
    return true;
}


public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item){
    switch (item.getItemId()){
        case R.id.menuHelp :
            return true;

        case R.id.menuShowInstallationCode :
            return true;

    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

Comment: the second `return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);` is an unreachable statement.

Comment: I'm sorry I made a mistake. Just remove the one from default.

Comment: @Fresheyeball Or change the return statement in `default` to call the correct function in the super class.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a complete code piece, tested on Android 2.2. I didn't create any XML for it, not necessary.

```
package com.samplemenu;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
    }

    static final int MENU_ONE = 0;
    static final int MENU_TWO = 1;    


    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        menu.add(0, MENU_ONE, 0, "One").setIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
        menu.add(0, MENU_TWO, 0, "Two").setIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
        return true;
    }   

    /* Handles item selections */
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case MENU_ONE: {

        }
        return true;

        case MENU_TWO: {

        }
        return true;

        }
        return false;
    }

}
```